# Change userInfo in timer selector function in Swift

Tags: swift, timer, userinfo

I want to update the userInfo of the timer in the selector function every time the timer fires.

userInfo:

```
var timerDic  = ["count": 0]
```

Timer:

```
Init:     let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:     Selector("cont_read_USB:"), userInfo: timerDic, repeats: true)
```

selector function:

```
public func cont_read_USB(timer: NSTimer)
{
  if var count = timer.userInfo?["count"] as? Int
  {
     count = count + 1

     timer.userInfo["count"] = count
  }
}
```

I get an error on the last line:

> 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

What is wrong here? 
In Objective_C this task worked with a `NSMutableDictionary` as `userInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimer.userInfo` is of type `AnyObject` so you need to cast it to your target object:

```
public func cont_read_USB(timer: NSTimer)
{
    if var td = timer.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,Int> {
        if var count = td["count"] {
            count += 1
            td["count"] = count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But note that this will modify only the local `td` dictionary, not the `timerDic` property (so the count would be zero on *every* call)

Comment: @MartinR: You are right, passing a reference to the `timerDic` property would be needed here. Better to modify the property object itself.

Answer (score 5):

To make this work, declare `timerDic` as an `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
var timerDic:NSMutableDictionary = ["count": 0]
```

Then in your `cont_read_USB` function:

```
if let timerDic = timer.userInfo as? NSMutableDictionary {
    if let count = timerDic["count"] as? Int {
        timerDic["count"] = count + 1
    }
}
```

Discussion:

- Swift dictionaries are value types, so if you want to be able to update it you have to pass an object.  By using an `NSMutableDictionary` you get an object type that is passed by reference, and it can be modified since it is a *mutable* dictionary.

---

**Complete example for Swift 4+:**

If you don't want to use an `NSMutableDictionary`, you can create your own `class`.  Here is a complete example using a custom `class`:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTimerInfo {
    var count = 0
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myTimerInfo = CustomTimerInfo()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: myTimerInfo, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func update(_ timer: Timer) {
        guard let timerInfo = timer.userInfo as? CustomTimerInfo else { return }

        timerInfo.count += 1
        print(timerInfo.count)
    }

}
```

When you run this in the simulator, the `count` that is printed increases every second.

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew, I just tried this in an app with Xcode 9.2 (latest) and Swift 4 and it worked.  I had to use `Timer` instead of `NSTimer` and add `@objc` to the timer update function, but it worked.  What symptoms are you seeing?

Comment: If I pass a bool in the userInfo, it's always false when it calls the function.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie, are you passing just a straight Bool, or is it the property of a class? Does the timer routine change the Bool?

Comment: I didn't want to also make that class property, so I just passed the straight Bool.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie, a Bool is a value type, so it will always just be the initial value. You need to pass an object that wraps your Bool.